# Does the sequence of (inner) joins matter based on number of records in tables used in join?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, sql-server-2008-r2, inner-join

I wanted to know if the sequence of joins (preferably INNER JOIN) matters in terms of execution time, based on number of records of tables used in join? If yes, then what should be the join sequence?

If possible, please explain with example in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

> Does the sequence of joins matter in terms of execution time based on number of records of tables used in join

While the SQL optimizer tries to optimize the execution plan, there is no guarantee that it will always produce the most optimal plan. When the number of joins is small and the WHERE clause is trivial, the optimizer will usually find an optimal plan. But if there are a lot of joins, a non-trivial WHERE clause and other constructs that may impact the optimizer, the optimizer can produce a non-optimal plan.

There is nothing wrong with helping the optimizer and make its task easier. Therefore it is generally best to have the joins resulting in the fewest rows first. But that is no guarantee for an optimal plan. Always profile your queries by checking the Actual Execution Plan, verifying IO/CPU stats and just measure execution speed.

Another boost for the optimizer is writing queries that aren't overly complex. The optimizer will do a better job for simpler queries. It helps to sometimes break extremely complex/deep queries down in smaller queries that store intermediate results in one or more temporary tables.

Note that the act of optimizing takes time as well, especially for complex queries. If you make it easy on the optimizer it will provide an optimized plan faster.

Comment: You could also mention query hints like `FORCE_ORDER` to make the answer more complete.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov I was thinking about that when I wrote that essay. However if `OPTION(FORCE ORDER)` is required it is usually because the query is too complex to optimize properly. In that case it is probably better to reduce query complexity or fix the underlying issue (missing INDEX comes to mind) rather than supplying an option like `FORCE ORDER`. I've personally never had the need for `FORCE ORDER` so I don't have a good real world case to illustrate it with (in words).